# Delivery is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, npm-install, meteor-blaze

I'm  using Meteor framework, and I'm trying to send an upload file (HTML input) from the client to the server using the `npm package Delivery`. Here is my code 
Client side :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://0.0.0.0:5001');

        socket.on('connect', function(){
            var delivery = new Delivery(socket);
            ...
            });
```

The console error said `ReferenceError: Delivery is not defined` ,
I installed the NPM Delivery package using the command line and using the framework ! but it doesn't recognize the Delivery class when the code is executed. 


Here is the trace of the error:

[image: Here is the trace of the error]

Any suggestions please !

Comment: Can you show a bit more code, please? Like the cli input when you installed it and the code where you import / require `io` and `socket`` in your file?

Comment: @Jankapunkt For the `io` i used `import io from 'socket.io-client';` and for `Delivery` i used `import  'delivery';`. The command line to install `socket` and `Delivery` are `  meteor npm install --save-dev meteor-node-stubs socket.io socket.io-client` and `sudo meteor npm install --save delivery`

Comment: https://github.com/Akryum/meteor-socket-io try to take a look at thus

Comment: https://forums.meteor.com/t/recommended-way-to-upload-images-in-meteor-no-plugins-no-external-services-solved/34678/10

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb The `socket-io` work just fine. I have an issue with `Delivery`, the browser can not find it reference during the execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if you r project is well importing the Delivery.js api
in your client side

try to import it using the delivery.js path if that works try to find how you'r environment manage deployment of API

Comment: You are wright, it work by importing the `delivery.js` but it is important to precise to full path like this `import '../../node_modules/delivery/lib/client/delivery.js';`. I tried before `import 'deviery' ` but it doesn't work because I taught the framework will recognize it automatically while i was installing the package using the `meteor npm install ...` . @MohammedHousseynTaleb  Thank you man.